# how to make the php add up the values of the form only when they are clicked?

Tags: php, html

i have a form in html that when the certain fields are clicked i want it to add up the values in the php part, so i thought that if i put the php part in the value area of the html then it would add it up, but it adds them all up but not the specific ones when clicked, Please help:

```
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="one" value= <?php $number = 2.39; ?> 
    <label for="one">Four 100-watt light bulbs for $2.39</label>
  <p>
```

```
 $total = $number + $numberone + $numbertwo + $numberthree;

 echo "Total cost is " .$total; 
 echo $card;
?>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to sum the total when the form gets submitted

Comment: If you are not checking the checkbox, you should get undefined variable error, wonder how it adds even if the checkbox value isn't submitted

Comment: Use AJAX with Javascript function to do the calculation on the fly.

Comment: if this is for an ecommerce site, you shouldn't be round-tripping prices through client-side forms. nothing would stop an even somewhat knowledgeable user from making that 80" plasma tv cost 0.01 instead of $lots.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to echo out the number value in your form, not just assign the variable, nothing will be rendered there.  Also, I find that if you're adding numbers for totals, it's easier to name them in a fashion that you can pull the values back out in an array

```
name="one"
```

would become

```
name="price[]"
```

or something of the like.

```
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value= <?php echo('2.39'); ?> 
  <label for="one">Four 100-watt light bulbs for $2.39</label>
</p>
```

Then on the server side, just sum the totals

```
$total = 0;
foreach($_POST['price'] AS $value){
  $total += $value;
}
```

You'll want to do some input sanitization, but this example should get you going.

This example will only work on the server-side after a form submission, if you want to add them up in realtime on the page, you'd have to use ajax to add the values up.

Comment: so then when you have all the values how do you make it so that the total will show up when the submit button is pressed?